# Why Windows 10 Mobile doesn't show how many rings my caller waited before hanging up If he rang more than one ring?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, notifications, calls, lumia-640-xl

I know that Windows 10 Mobile in previous Beta builds shows how many rings my caller waited before hanging up. This feature doesn't work properly in the latest final release on Lumia 640 XL . It only works if the caller calls me and instantly hangs up. When I return to my call history I find the caller and one ring. If the caller gives me more than one ring, Windows doesn't tell me how rings I received before the caller hanged up.

[image]

I think you misunderstood me. [Read this](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Latest-Windows-10-Mobile-build-shows-how-many-rings-your-caller-waited-before-hanging-up_id75071)

My Phone: Lumia 640 XL 
OS: Windows 10 Mobile

Comment: It is working fine for me. The numbers are shown for me in the brackets.

Comment: This isn't how many times the phone rang. It's how many times there was a phone exchange (you called them or they called you) in a set period of time. (I think it goes per day.)

Answer (score 0):

I am on build 10586.218, and it shows how many rings a caller made. 10586.218 build can be obtained via insider fast ring update[image]

Comment: I just wonder how you changed the font? Is there any option to change?

Comment: yeah, but you need to interop unlock your phone!

Comment: Those are not rings. Those are numbers of (missed) calls in the brackets. Check the screenshot in the question, and see that it shows 'one ring' before saying its a missed call. The question is asking specifically about that part